# mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) is really slow

Tags: php, mysql

This is my  MySQL query:

```sql
SELECT item_to_list_tb . * , item_tb . * , list_tb . * 
FROM item_to_list_tb, item_tb, list_tb
WHERE item_to_list_tb.list_id =3
AND item_to_list_tb.item_id = item_tb.item_id
GROUP BY item_to_list_tb.item_id
ORDER BY item_to_list_tb.item_ord
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

It takes 0.008 seconds when on a MySQL database directly.

However, when I get the results in PHP, if I use

```php
$result = mysql_query($sql, $this->svr_msconnect);
mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC));
```

it takes **4 seconds** to load!

Whereas, when I use

```php
$result = mysql_query($sql, $this->svr_msconnect);
mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

it takes the regular 0.008 seconds or so.

As far as I know, the con of `mysql_fetch_row` is that it doesn’t give the name of the columns. Is that right? That would mean that I would not be able to echo something like `$r['col_name']` but would instead have to use something like `$r[0][3]`. Is that right?

What alternatives are there?

Comment: it's not mysql_fetch_array issue for sure. You have to investigate more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `mysql_fetch_assoc($result);`

Below note from: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

**Note: Performance**
An important thing to note is that using **mysql_fetch_assoc()** is ***not significantly slower*** than using mysql_fetch_row(), while it provides a significant added value.